# S3 - Access-Control-Allow-Origin Header

Tags: google-chrome, cors, amazon-aws

Estou com dificuldades no acesso a um script .js armazenado em um Bucket S3 na AWS.

Já realizei a alteração de permissionamento do Bucket conforme abaixo:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "POST",
            "GET",
            "HEAD",
            "DELETE",
            "PUT"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "ETag"
        ],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]
```

Ao fazer a chamada do script via código, recebo o erro no console:

Access to script at 'https://www.cloudfront-buckets3-exemplo.com/RemoteEntry.js' from origin 'https://urlexemplo.com.br' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Porém fiz um teste via curl e obtive sucesso (HTTP 200), mesmo mudando a Origin conforme acima e o header está presente conforme evidência abaixo:

> curl -i https://www.cloudfront-buckets3-exemplo.com/RemoteEntry.js -H
> "Origin: [https://urlexemplo.com.br/"](https://urlexemplo.com.br/%22)

[image: Evidencia Curl]

Preciso de um apoio para conseguir resolver esta questão. Obrigado.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Identifiquei uma Policy no Cloudfront que estava realizando o bloqueio de CORS.

O Ajuste acima realizado no Bucket está correto e é necessário, porém também foi necessário fazer uma alteração no "Response Header Policy" no Cloudfront que aponta para este Bucket S3 para que o erro de CORS parasse de acontecer.